# Check if a table column exists in the database using SQLAlchemy and Alembic

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy, alembic

I'm using Alembic as migration tool and I'm launching the following pseudo script on an already updated database (no revision entries for Alembic, the database schema is just up to date).

```py
revision = '1067fd2d11c8'
down_revision = None

from alembic import op
import sqlalchemy as sa


def upgrade():
    op.add_column('box', sa.Column('has_data', sa.Boolean, server_default='0'))


def downgrade():
    pass
```

It gives me the following error only with PostgreSQL behind (it's all good with MySQL):

```
INFO  [alembic.migration] Context impl PostgresqlImpl.
INFO  [alembic.migration] Will assume transactional DDL.
INFO  [root] (ProgrammingError) ERREUR:  la colonne « has_data » de la relation « box » existe déjà
```

Last line means the column `has_data` already exists.

I want to check that the column exists before `op.add_column`.

Answer (score 12):

We ran into the same issue: we had to accommodate an edge case when a column added in a revision might exist in the schema. Silencing the error is not an option, as that will rollback the current transaction (unless using sqlite), and the version table will not be updated. Checking for column existence seems optimal here. Here's our solution (same idea as in the accepted answer, but updated for 2022):

```python
from alembic import op
from sqlalchemy import inspect

def column_exists(table_name, column_name):
    bind = op.get_context().bind
    insp = inspect(bind)
    columns = insp.get_columns(table_name)
    return any(c["name"] == column_name for c in columns)
```

This is called from a revision file, so the context accessed via `op.get_context()` has been configured (presumably in your `env.py`, and the `bind` exists.

Answer (score 8):

The easiest answer is not to try to do this.  Instead, make your Alembic migrations represent the full layout of the database. Then any migrations you make will be based off the changes to the existing database.

To make a starting migration if you already have a database, temporarily point at an empty database and run `alembic revision --autogenerate -m "base"`.  Then, point back at the actual database and run `alembic stamp head` to say that the current state of the database is represented by the latest migration, without actually running it.

If you don't want to do that for some reason, you can choose not to use `--autogenerate` and instead generate empty revisions that you fill in with the operations you want. Alembic won't stop you from doing this, it's just much less convenient.

Answer (score 7):

I am, unfortunately, in a situation where we have multiple versions with different schemas that all need to migrate to a single codebase.  There are no migrations anywhere yet and no versions tagged in any db.  So the first migration will have these conditional checks.  After the first migration, everything will be in a known state and I can avoid such hacks.

So I added this in my migration (credit belongs to http://www.derstappen-it.de/tech-blog/sqlalchemie-alembic-check-if-table-has-column):

```
from alembic import op
from sqlalchemy import engine_from_config
from sqlalchemy.engine import reflection

def _table_has_column(table, column):
    config = op.get_context().config
    engine = engine_from_config(
        config.get_section(config.config_ini_section), prefix='sqlalchemy.')
    insp = reflection.Inspector.from_engine(engine)
    has_column = False
    for col in insp.get_columns(table):
        if column not in col['name']:
            continue
        has_column = True
    return has_column
```

My upgrade function has the following checks (note that I have a batch flag set that adds the `with op.batch_alter_table` line, which probably isn't in most setups:

```
def upgrade():
    # ### commands auto generated by Alembic - please adjust! ###
    with op.batch_alter_table('mytable', schema=None) as batch_op:
        if not _table_has_column('mytable', 'mycol'):
            batch_op.add_column(sa.Column('mycol', sa.Integer(), nullable=True))
        if not _table_has_column('mytable', 'mycol2'):
            batch_op.add_column(sa.Column('mycol2', sa.Integer(), nullable=True))
```