# alembic create_table, check if table exists

Tags: python, database-migration, alembic

I have an alembic upgrade script that creates a table, however I don't want it to create the table if it already exists.

According to the [alembic doc](http://alembic.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ops.html#alembic.operations.Operations.create_table), I can pass in keyword args to `op.create_tables` that are acceptable to [sqlalchemy.schema.table](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Table), so I'm using the `keep_existing` keyword:

```
op.create_table('foo_model',
  sa.Column('foo_id', sa.Integer(), nullable=False),
  sa.Column('foo_str', sa.String(length=255), nullable=True),
  sa.PrimaryKeyConstraint('foo_id'),
  keep_existing= True
  )
```

However I'm still getting the table already exists error.

```
sqlalchemy.exc.InternalError: (InternalError) (1050, u"Table 'foo_model' already exists") '\nCREATE TABLE foo_model (\n\tfoo_id INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, \n\tfoo_str VARCHAR(255), \n\tPRIMARY KEY (foo_id)\n)\n\n' ()
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24082542/check-if-a-table-column-exists-in-the-database-using-sqlalchemy-and-alembic/52865284#52865284

Comment: Did you check why keep_existing is not working?

Answer (score 32):

You can get the list of existing tables like this:

```
from sqlalchemy.engine.reflection import Inspector

conn = op.get_bind()
inspector = Inspector.from_engine(conn)
tables = inspector.get_table_names()
```

and then check if table already exists or not

```
if table_name not in tables:
   op.create_table()
```

Comment: Just a note: `Inspector` means `sqlalchemy.engine.reflection.Inspector`

Comment: I have a lot having 100+ tables in different revisions, checking it separably on every create_table  doesn't seems like a good ideas, any generic solution for it?

Answer (score 4):

Here is a full solution if anyone wants

```
from alembic import op
from sqlalchemy import engine_from_config
from sqlalchemy.engine import reflection

def _has_table(table_name):
    config = op.get_context().config
    engine = engine_from_config(
        config.get_section(config.config_ini_section), prefix="sqlalchemy."
    )
    inspector = reflection.Inspector.from_engine(engine)
    tables = inspector.get_table_names()
    return table_name in tables
```

Comment: Using this method I get an exception for `KeyError: 'url'` when it tries to execute `engine_from_config`. I do not have a `url` key in my alembic config file.

Answer (score 0):

As it has been said elsewhere ( [Check if a table column exists in the database using SQLAlchemy and Alembic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24082542/check-if-a-table-column-exists-in-the-database-using-sqlalchemy-and-alembic)) alembic should reflect the full state of your database, that means it would automatically know if a table exists.

Make sure you define the upgrade and downgrade, so that if upgrade creates the table downgrade removes it.

If you do this you can just "downgrade" to the previous revision and upgrade again and it will work. Use autogenerate on a revision to create the initial state.

Answer (score -11):

It's probably because the table already exists. Just drop the table from your database by using `psql` and running `drop table foo_model;`

Comment: That's not really a solution to the problem of having migrations running fine by themselves when the table is already there. (plus dropping table is loosing data)